# local webIDE not connectig to es4 service

Tags: sapui5, web-ide, sap-web-ide

I have installed SAP WebIDE local on my machine and trying to connect with the below services:

```
https://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWBEP/GWSAMPLE_BASIC/?sap-ds-debug=true

http://services.odata.org/v3/northwind/northwind.svc/
```

I am getting two errors attached for reference.

[image: service unavailable error screenshot]

[image: not found error screenshot]

Below is my destination file1:

```
Description=es4
Type=HTTP
TrustAll=true
Authentication=NoAuthentication
WebIDEUsage=odata_abap
Name=es4
WebIDEEnabled=true
URL=https\://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com\:443
ProxyType=Internet
WebIDESystem=es4
```

File 2:

```
Description=es4
Type=HTTP
TrustAll=true
Authentication=NoAuthentication
WebIDEUsage=odata_gen
Name=es4
WebIDEEnabled=true
URL=https\://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com
ProxyType=Internet
WebIDESystem=es4
```

Is there any configuration needed in my local Cloud connector?

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't have separate files for the same destination. Please have it in one file and separate the WebIDEUsage values with commas (make sure there are no spaces). More information can be found in the documentation Hofit has added.

Second, there's no need in a Cloud Connector, as there's no cloud here. If you install Web IDE locally then it's installed in your local station, there's no connectivity to the cloud.

I'm sure you can find all the needed information in both the documentation and SAP community.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to connect to es4- as you did in the first screenshot and it is working fine. (the name in the service catalog dropdown should be es4 as the name in the destination file 1- and not es4123).

[Here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/CF/en-US/2cf47f37e34c428c97a51057733c0394.html) is a link to the documentation.

Comment: Hi Hofot, thanks for your reply. Agree in dropdown it should be es4. sorry for confusion, it was actually old screen shot. And I also followed same sap helplink shared by you.. Let me know if there is anything which I have to do in Cloud connector. if possible please share your cloud connector details so I can update same in my settings. Thanks-